# Excluding user from GPO - Permission object missing

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'm trying to exclude a user from a GPO. I've done this in the past using the steps explained in the link below:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/10/12/step-by-step-excluding-users-or-usergroups-from-group-policy/

This time, I don't see a "apply group policy" permission object under "advanced" section so I can't deny that permission. What could be missing? Has something changed since then?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: I was about to, but now I see the option there. I'm probably going blind.